# How to convert each value in a dictionary to a separate list?

Tags: python, list, rest, for-loop, flask

So I'm trying to convert the values in in `payload` to a separate list. The first value of fruits, I'm trying to place that in the `fruits` list and the same with the `vegetables`.

---

```
main.py

import requests

headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

list_of_fruits = ["orange", "banana", "mango"]
list_of_vegetables = ["squash", "brocoli", "aspharagus"]

payload = {
    "fruits": list_of_fruits
    "vegetables": list_of_vegetables
}

response = requests.post(f"127.1.1.1:9000/json", headers=headers, json=payload)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

flask_api.py

from flask import Flask, request

@app.route('/post_json', methods=['POST'])
def process_json():
    content_type = request.headers.get('Content-Type')
    if (content_type == 'application/json'):
        
        fruits= [] 
        vegetables = []
         
        data = request.json
        for k, v in data.items(): #How can I convert the first list of values to the fruits list? and the same for vegetables?
            print(v) ---> ["orange", "banana", "mango"]["squash", "brocoli", "aspharagus"]
        
        return data
    else:
        return 'Content-Type not supported!'

#Output ---> ["orange", "banana", "mango"]["squash", "brocoli", "aspharagus"]
```

Comment: What is the current output of your program?

Comment: Output is `["orange", "banana", "mango"]["squash", "brocoli", "aspharagus"]` Trying to convert the first list generated from the for loop on line 25 in the `flask_api.py` section to the `fruits` list 21 and the second list to the `vegetables` list on line 22

Comment: `fruits, vegetables = data.get('fruits'), data.get('vegetables')`

Comment: @sahasrara62 This is perfect! I knew there was some pythonic way of doing it! I don't think there's a way I can select your comment as an answer on here tho?

Comment: @SuperDummy added. above comment as solution with little explaination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to read the data from request. your request is in form somehting like this

```
{
   'fruits': ['list of fruits'],
   'vegetables': ['list of vegetables']

}
```

you are reading request data in json format using `data = requests.json`, which is of same format as above mentioned.

now to read/save  the data in list, you need to read the data from `data` dictionary and save it in list.

```
fruits = data.get('fruits', []) # [] in case no 'fruits' as key value in payload
vegetables = data.get('vegetables', [])
```

Here `fruits` and `vegetables` are list you save your data.